# Replace non-ascii character by ascii code using java regex

Tags: java, regex, non-ascii-characters

I have string like this `T 8.ESTÜTESTतुम मेरी`. Now using java regex i want to replace non-ascii character `Ü`, `तुम मेरी` with its equivalent code.

How can i achieve this?

I can replace it with any other string.

`String str = "T 8.ESTÜTESTतुम मेरी";

String resultString = str.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
System.out.println(resultString);`

It prints `T 8.ESTTEST`

Comment: What do you want to do with `ק`?

Comment: you need http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html

Comment: none of this work, normalization may not work at this situation.

Comment: @Pritom When you say "replace with its equivalent code", by "code" do you mean an ascii value that's mapped to that unicode value, or the unicode reference number?

Comment: It is ascii code, suppose A=65, B=66 etc.

Comment: sorry, but does those chars have any ascii code? (sorry for my ignorance)

Comment: Ok, it is actually not ASCII value, its Unicode value, is it right now?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know how to do this using a single regex, please check if this works for you

```
    String str = "T 8.ESTÜTESTतुम मेरी";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        if (String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)).matches("[^\\p{ASCII}]")){
            sb.append("[CODE #").append((int)str.charAt(i)).append("]");
        }else{
            sb.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

prints

```
T 8.EST[CODE #220]TEST[CODE #2340][CODE #2369][CODE #2350] [CODE #2350][CODE #2375][CODE #2352][CODE #2368]
```

the problem seems to be how to tell regex how to convert what it finds to the code.

Comment: I can do it using for loop, but i need using regex.

Comment: I don't know if you can apply functions to the regex replacement. Also I don't know if this poses a serious performance impact for you. Well, let's see if anyone else has a way to solve your problem using a single regex line then.